# Can any metric space be completed?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Completion defined in Real Analysis, Carothers, 1ed has been captured below.
[image]

Can any metric space be completed?

Comment: As a starting point for thinking about this, one can consider $\Bbb R$ as the collection of Cauchy sequences in $\Bbb{Q}$ under an equivalence relation.

Comment: Google "completion of a metric space" and click on the second link (the first probably works too)

Comment: @Trevor Wilson: Google customizes its search results to one's browsing history ( which Google keeps track of) , so there is no way of knowing what the second link will be for someone else. Somehow, the fact that you got that link as your second link says something of what Google thinks of you from your search and surfing history.

Comment: @DBFdalwayse Oops, good point.  Good thing I didn't say "and click the seventh link, after [insert embarrassing search results here]" :-)

Comment: @Trevor Wilson: No problem; that second link I got was the hottest porn site I've seen in years :).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Rudin outlines a proof in *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*, Chapter 3, Problem 24.

Given a metric space $(X,d)$, say two Cauchy sequences $(p_n)$ and $(q_n)$ are equivalent if $\lim_{n\to\infty} d(p_n,q_n) = 0$. This is an equivalence relation on the set of all Cauchy sequences, as you can verify.

The set of all equivalence classes, say $X^*$, can be given a metric: if $P$ and $Q$ are equivalence classes in $X^*$ and $(p_n)\in P$, $(q_n)\in Q$ are representatives for the equivalence classes, set $\Delta(P,Q) = \lim_{n\to\infty} d(p_n,q_n)$. It can be shown that this is a metric on $X^*$. Moreover, $(X^*, \Delta)$ is a complete metric space, and there is an isometry of $X$ into $X^*$, so $(X^*, \Delta)$ is a completion of $(X,d)$ by Carothers's definition of the term.

This is an excellent exercise, and I highly encourage you to find a copy of Rudin and try it out. He gives more details and hints in his outline, so with substantial effort you should be able to give it a good go.

Comment: Does make sense a lot! really appreciate ur help^_^

Answer (score 3):

Cauchy sequences are a standard method of completing a metric space. An alternative method of completion of a metric space $(M, d)$ is given by the Kuratowski embedding into the space of bounded functions $M \to \mathbb R$. Exercise: prove that this space of bounded functions forms a complete metric space under the metric $\hat d(f, g) = \displaystyle\sup_{x \in M} |f(x)-g(x)|$. If we name this metric space $N$, and let $x_0$ be an arbitrary element of $M$, then $M$ embeds into $N$ by the map $x \mapsto \{y \mapsto d(x,y)-d(x,x_0)\}$. The purpose of subtracting $d(x,x_0)$ is simply to ensure the map is bounded. Exercise: prove this gives an isometric embedding. Then the completion $\hat M$ is just given by the closure of the image of this embedding.

Comment: The metric on $\ell^\infty(M)$ should be $\hat d(f,g) = \lVert f-g\rVert_\infty := \sup_{x\in M} \lvert f(x) - g(x)\rvert$, right?

Comment: Yes, thank you.